# Can I change the PHP start and end tags?

Tags: php, customization

Can I change the PHP start and end tags?

Like if I modify the core library files and have something like

```
<!J
```

or

```
!#RR
```

In replacement of

```
<? ?>  or <?php ?>
```

## Update

For those voting a close. Believe me there are people who will always ask this. For those wanting to know why? *sighs*

Yes I know about Nginx rewrite, Apache Handlers, Hiding code, remove extensions etc.. For me personally.. I like the idea of my own programming language I wish to create in future. Therefore re-writing tags on an existing template type language that uses C type libraries would be a start. I would get excited every time I start writing the vain for me is Here come the downvotes

Comment: Why, if I may ask? Where's the benefit of such thing?

Comment: What on earth would the point of this be?

Comment: I'm sure you could if you edited PHP's source then re-compiled it, but there is no setting that will let you change this.  The only valid tags are `<?php ?>` and `<? ?>`/`<?= ?>` (if `short_open_tag` is on).  Heck, if you enable `asp_tags`, you can use `<% %>` and `<%= %>`!

Comment: This would be handy, because `<?` is too long to type.

Comment: Go for it.  There's nothing to lose by trying.

Comment: yes, not easily, and a bad idea.

Comment: PHP already has two alternative styles for start and end tags.

Comment: It's a legitimate technical question. Let's find an answer.

Comment: There's better ways to try and obfuscate code.

Comment: @PenguinCoder sherlock holmes ;)

Comment: Since [PHP source code](http://php.net/downloads.php) is available, you may modify anything you like, and set the start and end tags to anything you want.

Comment: Let's see a creative answer. A step-by-step would be nice. I like folks who challenge the norm and think outside the box. I think in the end we will all have learned a little more about the PHP code base and how it all works. Looks to me like a healthy technical exercise. I'd put a bounty on it. :-)

Comment: @BryanAllo - There is nothing mysterious about it. You change the source code. Done.

Comment: @relentless - Maybe you can post an answer and share with all these curious minds then? Thanks.

Comment: as long as you don't expect to be able to run any OTHER php script out of the box, you can customize PHP to look for whatever open/close tags you want.

Comment: @DamienPirsy signs.. question updated. Thanks for all the responses..

Comment: I vote for reopen. While some may not believe *what* the question asks is *constructive*, I believe it as well as its comments and answers are *constructive* to future readers.

Comment: @Jason - I agree. We cannot embrace the concept of community and afford to see everyone's technical challenge through the filter of our own limited experiences. This question is very constructive IMHO. It is clear that a lot of folks have no idea about the inner workings of an open platform such as PHP. It's a bit disconcerting that more folks were quick to evaluate with great certainty and spend more time refuting than simply answering this Man's seemingly simple question as he seeks to accomplish whatever he set out to do. I've seen some ridiculous questions on here. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented, PHP is an open source project. Therefore, you can [modify it](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php) for personal use.

Ultimately this would involve updating the language syntax. From quickly poking around the [PHP project on Github](https://github.com/php/php-src/), I found the [language scanner](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l). Changing the [appropriate definitions](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#L1726) from `php` to whatever you want should allow you to customize the open/close tags.

**Note:** I do not advocate this whatsoever. And therefore haven't tested such a solution. Although it should work in theory.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and posting your answer Jason.

Comment: +1 .. what a fantastic well found answer. Exactly to the correct line .. just need a compilation and some tweaks. Perfect. +1 for not knowing PHP was on Github.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - I'm glad you found what you needed. PHP (and the open source community at large) would not be what it is today of it weren't for folks like you inquiring and making the technology do exactly what you want it to do - no matter how ridiculous it may seem to someone else. Hopefully you can begin contributing to the community someday. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

As insane as this sounds, it appears that it is possible to crack open the hood of the php core code and modify it if you need to:

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php

Comment: It's open source. You can do ANYTHING you want with it. open-source i.e. the source code is OPEN

Comment: As the document says: Those who know don't talk. Those who talk don't know. I see a lot of people talking. Thanks for sharing your answer with us.

Comment: +1 for finding the information on this. Thank you.

Comment: `As soon as this point is reached, it's time to touch the heart of PHP and take a look at its core, the C code that makes PHP go.` HARD ON